# Realm Filter nested Array

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm, realm-list

I have three object

```swift
class YearDatabaseModel: Object {
    @Persisted var year: Int
    @Persisted var months = List<MonthsDatabaseModel>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "year"
    }
}
```

```swift
final class MonthsDatabaseModel: Object {
    @Persisted var id: String
    @Persisted var media = List<Model>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

```swift
public class Model: Object {
    @Persisted public var id: String
    @Persisted public var type: String
}
```

I need to return all the Year models with filter nested Month. Model items with their type for example just return models items in month with type == "audio"

I did use this `SUBQUERY` but it just filter the year list not filter the model list

```swift
 let predicate = NSPredicate(
                format: "SUBQUERY(months.media, $media, $media.type = %@).@count > 0",
 "audio")
```

And I don't want to get the realm result then filter models by flat mapping the list of models I want to use realm query power to filter neseted objects from big model

Here's a diagram

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very challenging query due to the depth and dealing with `Lists`, but the subquery is likely the best solution unless you want to leverage high-level Swift functions.

I *think* this will get your result but it's a two part query. As is, the current SwiftSDK doesn't have a (good) implementation for subqueries per se so I'm using an old school NSPredicate combined with the newer type safe query to get the result

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(media, $m, $m.type == 'm0 type 0').@count > 0")
let months = realm.objects(MonthsDatabaseModel.self).filter(predicate)

let years = realm.objects(YearDatabaseModel.self).where { $0.months.containsAny(in: months) }
print(years)
```

We use the subquery to get all of the months `MonthsDatabaseModel` that have a `Model` with `type = "audio"`

Then we use those results to get the `YearDatabaseModel` that have months in their list that match.

Edit:

Here's a sample set of data (that matches the diagram in the question, noting there were two Year 2's so I used 2022 and 2023)

```
year 2021
 month:  year 2021 month 1
  media: video
  media: image
  media: video
 month:  year 2021 month 2
  media: image
  media: image
  media: image
 month:  year 2021 month 3
  media: video
  media: image
  media: video

year 2022  (note, no video media values in the child list)
 month:  year 2022 month 1
  media: image
  media: image
  media: image

year 2023
 month:  year 2023 month 1
  media: video
  media: image
  media: image
```

and when the code above is run against that data this it returns year 2021 and year 2023, omitting year 2022 because it does not have any video child values in the media List

```
year 2021
year 2023
```

Comment: unfortunately, this approach doesn't work 
I mean the media not filtered in the months

Comment: @AmirArdalan Hmm. It is working for me; it filters for the `MonthsDatabaseModel` based on the type and then filters on the `YearDatabaseModel` based on the months returned in the first query. Maybe if you can present some example data we can move it further along?

Comment: I don't want to filter the MonthsDatabaseMode I need to filter media in the MonthsDatabseModel and retrieve all the months which has data, sorry If I can't explain my issue correctly at first

Comment: @AmirArdalan I think I can answer this but I am not sure about what you're asking. The 'MonthsDatabaseModel` has a `media` property but that property is a `List` of `Model` objects. So the filter will need to be on one of of the `Model` object properties - either `id` or `type`. The subquery presented in my answer uses the `type` property to get whatever type you want. I used a string of `m0 type 0` to represent month 0, type 0 as that's what I my objects are populated with. The net results is the subquery returning all months that have data, at least in the type property.

Comment: The first thing I would like to say is that I appreciate your effort in answering my questions and for trying to help me

I drew a visual to better explain the issue and what I expect after applying the query. Here is the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DAeXk766lVXnu-DOnEATUJ-1tC_zafiD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AmirArdalan I took you image and put it in the question for clarity. You also have two Year 2, so I assume the second one is Year 3.

Comment: @AmirArdalan Here's the issue; you can't selectively return a high level object with a list and then omit items within the List. In other words, based on your setup, the Result section in your diagram; Item 2 from Year 1 Month 1 cannot be omitted - it's part of that list. However, if the objective is to return Year 1 and Year 3 (omitting the first Year 2 with only image types), that can be done. Believe it or not, the code in my answer does exactly that - it returns Year 1 and Year 3 only, omitting year 2. Tested it based on your data, see the EDIT in the answer